# Oracle Forms : Could not reserve record (2 tries) Keep trying?

Tags: oracleforms

Error Could not reserve record (2 tries) Keep trying? in oracle forms. Could anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+reserve+record+(2+tries)+Keep+trying

Comment: Did you even try google?

Comment: Dear James, I have tried googling a lot but only answer I'm getting is Network issue.But somehow I kept Null inside ON-LOCK trigger and it's working now form me.

Comment: I don't believe that at all. I don't know how you get this error but I found a lot of different things immediately.

Answer (score 0):

first of all,

> the default locking mode is automatic

if you want all session can access this record but last commit done and don't give you message change data block property (locking mode to be delayed).

Besides using `ON-LOCK` trigger, you may follow strategy below for forms :

> ```
> Let's have a data block named db_t1 ( table t1 as "query data source name" ). 
> Not only setting "locking mode" of db_t1 from "automatic" to "delayed", 
> but also set forms' "isolation mode" to "serializable".
> ```